# CSS fixed position moves while scrolling on mobile devices

Tags: ios, css

i have a full screen layer for mobile devices and use these css lines:

```
#buttons{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: yellow;
    z-index: 99999;
}
```

Whenever I scroll the page, the fixed layer slightly moves on top until it disappears completely. Any idea how to prevent this? Thanks very much!

Comment: instead of giving it a width and height, try bottom:0; and right:0;

Comment: That places the div at the very bottom of the page. I need it fixed within my viewport.

Comment: did you keep the top and left as well as adding the bottom and right?

Comment: Yes. Moves with the scrolled content. Not as fast as the other content, but slightly until it is completely gone.

Comment: fixed should fix it relative to the view port but I have had problems with it in the past.  have you tried moving the buttons element into the body root (you can do this using your js before showing it)

Comment: Yes, i tried that recently with no success. According to Google results I am not the only one struggling with it :(

Comment: I don't get how you are still able to scroll when you have an overlay covering the whole screen. very strange - never had that problem myself